# Joomla Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session

Tags: installation, joomla, localserver

It seems that in the `getApplication($id = null, array $config = array(), $prefix = 'J')` function (libraries/src/Factory.php) the site id  ($id in this case) is valid only once. If the check for `!self::$application` is false, the $id check causs the`Error: Failed to start application: Failed to start the session`. On my colleague's system, there is no error, even though the siteid is only valid the first time getApplication() is called. What would be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It appears there were several things that needed to be corrected in the config file, such as passwords and paths to get the site working. After I got it loading, I still had to deal with path issues which ended up being cpanel stuff at the end of the .htaccess file. Stripping those out worked.